# How to include a variable in a block WITH..AS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query to retrieve for each employee, his main and secondary function:

```
DECLARE @mainFunctionId INT

SELECT TOP 1 
    @mainFunctionId = FunctionId 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [le].[EmployeeId], [le].[FunctionId],[le].[Label], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [le].[EmployeeId] ORDER BY [le].[SortOrder] ASC) AS [RealOrder] 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              [e].[EmployeeId], [es].[FunctionId], ef.Label, ISNULL([es].[SortOrder], 9999) AS [SortOrder]
          FROM 
              [Employee] [e] 
          INNER JOIN 
              [Employee_Scope] AS [es] ON [es].[EmployeeId] = [e].[EmployeeId] 
          INNER JOIN
              [Employee_Function] AS [ef] ON es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId) [le]) [emp]

SELECT DISTINCT 
    [emp].[EmployeeId], [emp].[FunctionId],[emp].Label, IIF(@mainFunctionId = emp.FunctionId,'main','secondary')
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [le].[EmployeeId], [le].[FunctionId], [le].[Label], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [le].[EmployeeId] ORDER BY [le].[SortOrder] ASC) AS [RealOrder] 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              [e].[EmployeeId], [es].[FunctionId],ef.Label, ISNULL([es].[SortOrder], 9999) AS [SortOrder]
          FROM 
              [Employee] [e] 
          INNER JOIN 
              [Employee_Scope] AS [es] ON [es].[EmployeeId] = [e].[EmployeeId] 
          INNER JOIN 
              [Employee_Function] AS [ef] ON es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId) [le]) [emp]
```

**Output :** 
[image] 
I want to integrate my previous query in the source query of my dimension :

```
SELECT 
    [E].[EmployeeId], [E].[AdminFileId], [E].[Lastname] + ' ' + [E].[Firstname] AS [Name], [ES][Status]
FROM 
    [Employee] AS [E] 
INNER JOIN 
    [EmployeeStatus] AS [ES] ON [ES].[EmployeeStatusId] = [E].[EmployeeStatusId]
```

My expected output will be (for employee having EmployeeId=1) :

```
EmployeeId  AdminFileId  Name       Status Label                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1           23544        Marco Polo IN     Manager        main 
1           23544        Marco Polo IN     Senior  Account secondary 
1           23544        Marco Polo IN     Office Manager secondary
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want to integrate my previous query in the source query of my dimension.

Comment: I am missing something. The title of your question seems to about using a variable in a cte but the question is completely different. And just repeating a vague question is not helping others understand what you want. You need to provide some table definitions and sample data.

Comment: Given that it seems to be purely sortorder that defines main or secondary functions, why don't you just use the row_number () over() that you already calculate and `case when rownum = 1 them 'main' else 'secondary' end`?

Comment: @CaiusJard I am asking about how to link it to the second query ?

Comment: I also notice you have TOP 1 but there is no order by. How do you know which row you are going to get? Hint, you don't. With no order by it will return a row but you don't know for sure which one it will be.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help, as would setting up a fiddle of some sort.

Comment: I'm saying I think you don't need to. I think. You're trying to select top 1 per employee to get the main and union the others on to get the secondaries. I'm saying it can be done all in one hit using a row number on sortorder and partitioned by employee

Comment: @GordonLinoff I already shared the desired output.

Comment: That's great that you shared the desired output. But we don't know what the sample data is to get that output.

Comment: @SeanLange I added the output for the first query.

Comment: Sigh...glad you found an answer but the output is meaningless without knowing the input. You were asked several time to provide sample data. Please do that on future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

> How to include a variable in a block

are you asking how can you use `@mainFunctionId` for each employee?  And perhaps when you mention "with...as" are you hinting that you feel a CTE is perhaps the way to go?

If so, I would get away from the variable mindset altogether.  Also, in your first query, you don't reveal what you want to order by to get the top item.  But since you have the 'RealOrder' column in it, I'm guessing that is your intention.

Below I've simplified your second query.  "Distinct" is negated by your use of row_number.  There is no need for it, or, if there is, you've got to rework your query.  The nesting of the subqueries to produce the isnull around the sort order is not needed.  You can be more direct and just create that in the row_number function.  Other simplifications are more just a matter of style.

After the simplifications, I simply wrapped the core query into a CTE, and from the referencing query I made use of the previously calculated realOrder column to identify main and secondary records.

```
with

    employeeScopeFunctions as (

        select      e.employeeId, 
                    es.FunctionId,
                    ef.Label, 

                    realOrder = row_number() over(
                        partition by le.employeeId
                        order by isnull(es.sortOrder, 9999)
                    )

        from        employee e 
        join        employee_scope es on es.employeeId = e.employeeId
        join        employee_function ef on es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId

    )

    select      *,
                primacy = iif(realOrder = 1, 'main', 'secondary')
    from        employeeScopeFunctions
```

Comment: FYI, I'm a little out of line even answering this question because I'm making too many assumptions about what you want.  However, I need my mental jump start for the day and so I took on a refactoring of your code.  At any rate, i'd follow the advice of others and better clarify your needs in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query can be reduced to something like:

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Id ORDER BY COALESE(es.SortOrder, 9999)) = 1 THEN 'main' ELSE 'secondary' END
FROM 
  Employee e
  INNER JOIN Employee_Scope es ON es.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
  INNER JOIN Employee_Function ef ON es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId
```

This joins all your employee data together. The row_number establishes an incrementing counter on order of SortOrder. The number restarts from 1 for every different employee id (it's the purpose of the partition by clause) and this drives how every employee can have a main and then multiple secondaries